# Python AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_price'

Tags: python, string, tkinter, python-3.5, attributeerror

I am trying to take user input from main.py and then tailor the output to said user input. Not only am I getting this error but it seems the my runAnalytics is running when I start main.py, not when I hit my button command to do so.

main.py

```
import runAnalytics
import tkinter
import os
import centerWindow

loadApplication = tkinter.Tk()
loadApplication.title("Stock Analytics")
loadApplication.geometry("1080x720")

label1 = tkinter.Label(loadApplication, text = "Ticker")
input1 = tkinter.Entry(loadApplication)

loadAnalytics = tkinter.Button(loadApplication, text = "Load Analytics", command = runAnalytics.run(input1))

centerWindow.center(loadApplication)

loadAnalytics.pack()
label1.pack()
input1.pack()

loadApplication.mainloop()
```

runAnalytics.py

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
import tkinter
import os
import centerWindow

def run(input1):
    ticker = Share(input1)
    loadAnalytics = tkinter.Tk()
    loadAnalytics.title("$" + ticker + " Data")
    loadAnalytics.geometry("1080x720")

    print ("Price per share: " + ticker.get_price())

    ticker.refresh()
    print ("Price per share: " + ticker.get_price())

    print("The dividend yield is: " + ticker.get_dividend_yield())

    print("The 52 week low is: " + ticker.get_year_low())
    print("The 52 week high is: " + ticker.get_year_high())
    print("The volume is: " + ticker.get_volume())

    print("The previous close was: " + ticker.get_prev_close())
    print("The previous open was: " + ticker.get_open())

    loadAnalytics.mainloop()
```

Error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Python Projects\MarketData\main.py", line 13, in 
>           loadAnalytics = tkinter.Button(loadApplication, text = "Load Analytics", command = runAnalytics.run(input1))
>         File "C:\Users\MyName\Documents\Python Projects\MarketData\runAnalytics.py", line 12, in run
>           print ("Price per share: " + ticker.get_price())
>       AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_price'

Comment: strange indeed. Can you insert `print(type(ticker))` before and share the results?

Comment: Your problem is with Share who does not return an object as you might expect, but a string. That's why python can't find the "get_price" attribute.

Comment: Is the source code of `def run(input1):` cited here really exactly the same as you are running? It looks that `Share` object is `str` but that should never happen given the `yahoo_finance` API.

Comment: Yes everything I have posted here is exactly what I am running.

Comment: I commented out all interferences and added "print(type(ticker))". I received this output: <class 'yahoo_finance.Share'> @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: Are you sure that `input1` is a valid share code?

Comment: I am noticing that when I run my application without using the user input, both functions are being called. This is very strange, I am new to programming but perhaps it is automatically passing it some kind of null value and that is being accepted as a user input??

Comment: @Trimax I am not fully understanding your question. input1 is using the input feature through tkinter and then I am passing that to Share, which is part of the yahoo-finance module. Yahoo finance says that share should look something like this ...Share('AAPL')

Comment: Comment the line: `loadAnalytics.title("$" + ticker + " Data")` and try run it again.

Comment: I did that and then it raises an issue with the next line trying to use ticker. Saying that I have a type error and that I can't "convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly". I will accept albert's answer and then create a new question about this as it appears to be an entirely different error! @Trimax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption that `runAnalytics` is running is correct since the function is executed when binding it to the button the way you did.

According to the [effbot docs](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm) you need to use a `lambda` function in order to bind a function with passed arguments to a button like this:

```
import tkinter

def test_func(val):
    print(type(val))
    print(val)
    share_id = val.get()
    print(share_id)


loadApplication = tkinter.Tk()
loadApplication.title("Stock Analytics")
loadApplication.geometry("1080x720")

label1 = tkinter.Label(loadApplication, text = "Ticker")
input1 = tkinter.Entry(loadApplication)

loadAnalytics = tkinter.Button(loadApplication, text="Load Analytics", command=lambda: test_func(input1))


loadAnalytics.pack()
label1.pack()
input1.pack()

loadApplication.mainloop()
```

However, there is a second thing to keep in mind:

```
input1 = tkinter.Entry(loadApplication)
```

creates an `Entry` widget called `input1` which is then passed to the function. The thing is that `input1` does not contain the string you typed into the entry widget but a reference to the widget (widget ID). In order to get the widget's content you need to call its `.get()` method as shown in my code snippet.

Comment: Okay thank you! That fixed the issue of them both running! As I said earlier, I am new to this. Can you explain what the "def test_func(val): print(val)" is doing?

Comment: I commented it out and the program still ran.

Comment: You need to bind a callback function to a button which is executed whenever the button is clicked. Since I was in need of a simple sample callback and do not have the `yahoo_fincance` module installed on my system I decided to go this way. The porgramm code is not updated 'on-line' like live-reloading. So to make any changes working and see what's the difference you need to start and restart the whole script.

Comment: After reading your edit, I changed `ticker = Share(input1)` to `ticker = Share(input1.get())` and my problem was resolved! I wish I could upvote your answer twice. Thank you so much, I was working on this all day and the simplest error got me tied up. @albert